# Javascript alert not popping

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a very basic form validation in JS. I want it to pop an alert to let the user know that either the form was submitted, or if there was an error in the form. But for some reason the function isn't validating the information provided or is not popping any alert. Does anyone have any idea?

```js
let fields = {};

class User{
    constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, email, questions) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    fields.firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    fields.lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
    fields.phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    fields.email = document.getElementById('email');
    fields.questions = document.getElementById('questions');
   })

function isNotEmpty(value) {
    if (value == null || typeof value == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return (value.length > 0);
    }
}

function isNumber(number) {
    return (number.length) > 0 && !isNaN(num);
}

function isEmail(email) {
    let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
    return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function fieldValidation(field, validationFunction) {
    if (field == null)
        return false;
    let isFieldValid = validationFunction(field.value)
    if (!isFieldValid) {
        field.className = "placeholder"
    } else {
        field.className = '';
    }
    return isFieldValid
}

function isValid() {
    var valid = true;
    
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.firstName, isNotEmpty);
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.lastName, isNotEmpty);
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.phone, isNotEmpty);
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.email, isEmail);
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.questions, isNumber);
    return valid;
}

function sendContact() {
    if (isValid()) {
        let usr = new User(firstName.value, lastName.value, phone.value, email.value, questions.value);
        
        alert('${usr.firstName} ${user.lastName}, thank you. We will contact you as soon as we can.');
    } else {
        alert('There was an error in the form');
    }
}
```

```html
<form >
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="firstname" class="col-4 col-form-label">First Name</label> 
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="lastname" class="col-4 col-form-label">Last Name</label> 
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="phone" class="col-4 col-form-label">Phone Number</label> 
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label">Email Address</label> 
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="questions" class="col-4 col-form-label">Questions/Comments?</label> 
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea id="questions" name="questions" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-5" onclick = "sendContact()" >Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any JS errors?

Comment: I have, and nothing is popping. That is, there were the usual typos that I've already fixed.

Comment: `num` is not defined in `return (number.length) > 0 && !isNaN(num);`.

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected that typo. I'm still not popping an alert.

Comment: `document.getElementById('firstName')` is `null` because there is no element with `id="firstName"` (only one with `id="firstname"`).

Comment: Another one I've just corrected, thank you. I've also fixed lastname from the HTML.

Comment: A big problem that you are having isn't your javascript, its actually your HTML itself. Whenever a button is in a form and it doesn't have a type=button as an attribute it automatically becomes a SUBMIT button and submits the form. So you are actually submitting the form when pressing that button. A simple solution is to add **type="button"** to your button. Now if you are still going to want to allow the form to be submitted to a server side resource, you will need to run that on submit of the form and not onclick of the button

Comment: `firstName` is not defined in the `sendContact()` function (but `fields.firstName` is defined).

Comment: I'm getting an alert window with "There was an error in the form". I'm using Firefox. As @imvain2 said, the default type of the button is "submit". You need to delay the form submition (ie: prevent the event default behavior). Maybe it's redirecting before showing the alert window.

Comment: Bingo that was my problem! Thank you! I went ahead and changed my button HTML to  <button class="btn btn-primary mb-5" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>, and added document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = sendContact to the JS, and it's working perfect. Thank you so muhc!

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
class User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, email, questions) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.questions = questions;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  fields.firstName = document.getElementById('firstname');
  fields.lastName = document.getElementById('lastname');
  fields.phone = document.getElementById('phone');
  fields.email = document.getElementById('email');
  fields.questions = document.getElementById('questions');
})

function isNotEmpty(value) {
  if (value == null || typeof value == 'undefined') {
    return false;
  } else {
    return (value.length > 0);
  }
}

function isNumber(number) {
  return (number.length) > 0 && !isNaN(number);
}

function isEmail(email) {
  let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
  return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function fieldValidation(field, validationFunction) {
  if (field == null)
    return false;
  let isFieldValid = validationFunction(field.value)
  if (!isFieldValid) {
    field.className = "placeholder"
  } else {
    field.className = '';
  }
  return isFieldValid
}

function isValid() {
  var valid = true;

  valid &= fieldValidation(fields.firstName, isNotEmpty);
  valid &= fieldValidation(fields.lastName, isNotEmpty);
  valid &= fieldValidation(fields.phone, isNotEmpty);
  valid &= fieldValidation(fields.email, isEmail);
  return valid;
}

function sendContact() {
  console.log({ fields })
  if (isValid()) {
    let user = new User(fields.firstName.value, fields.lastName.value, fields.phone.value, fields.email.value, fields.questions.value);
    alert(`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}, thank you. We will contact you as soon as we can.`);
  } else {
    alert('There was an error in the form');
  }
}
```

Pay attention to variable names, html field ids and use backticks with ${}.
I am not going to refactor it, but I removed validation for the Questions/Comments.